# jquery valdaite custom error message and also revert back to default

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to setup the validate plugin so that:

1. If the form field has a class of "required" it will add a class to the field instead of displaying the error message below. Large form is getting too messy if we have lots of "This field is required"
2. But then I only want this to work in this way for `.required` fields, all other validation should revert back to the default.

This is what I have so far:

```
var theForm = $("form[method=post]:not(.noValidate)");
if (theForm.length){
    validater = theForm.validate({
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {  
            var i, length = errorList.length;
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if($(errorList[i].element).hasClass("required")){
                    $(errorList[i].element).addClass("error-required");
                } else {                
                    this.defaultShowErrors();
                }
            }
        }
     });
}
```

Its half working by adding the `.error-requied` to only required fields, although it still displays the message below each field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what is displaying the validation error, such as built-in html5 browser or a third-party javascript library. If you are using HTML5 forms, you can disable the form validation by using the "novalidate" in your form tag, which in turn, will disable the validation tags (supposed to disable the tags).

```
<form method="post" novalidate>
```

If you are using html5 and using the 'required' attribute on your input fields, you can do the following:

```
$('form[method=post]').find('[required]').addClass('error-required');
```

Otherwise, you can find the fields with the required class by using the following:

```
$('form[method=post]').find('.required').addClass('error-required');
```

This accesses only the required fields and adds the class instead of needing to loop over each of the form fields and checking if it's required.